# How ArcSegment works ? Radius not a real radius?

Tags: wpf

I draw an arc with arcsegment a change its coords (start point and point) programmaticaly. I set a default Size to (50,50). At the screen, the arc really changes (grows when values of start point and point change), but the size is never updated (always 50,50). The MSDN says that size property is the radius of the arc, so why this values are never changed  ?

I find a way to calculate the real radius from start, end point and the middle point of the arc and is really different. I wish to change the radius with mouse, but how to do that if the radius property is not a really one (which property to set) ?

Thanks for your help !

```XML
<Path Name="ConnecteurPath" Stroke="Black">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure x:Name="pthFigure" >
                <ArcSegment x:Name="arcSeg" IsLargeArc="True"
                            Size="50, 50"
                            SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: See the *Remarks* section in [ArcSegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.arcsegment.aspx).